# Issues in add validate email in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
 <form method="post" name="form1" action="invitation_enrollv5.asp?action=1" onSubmit="return GetTextValue()">

<input style="float:right;" id="nextbutton" name="" type="submit" value="Next" />       
</form>
```

May i know, how and where can i add validate script to validate input email address.

If i blank or invalid id means it shows error states.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: i used something like this     function validate() {
                    var x=document.forms['mailcontact']['email'].value; 
    
                    if (x == '' || x == null || x == ' name') {
                        alert("You need to enter a name");
                    }
                                       else {
                        document.forms['maincontact'].submit();
                    }
                } .. but it didn't work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For input boxes, you can specify the type as email, and the browser will validate for you.

`<input type="email" required>`

Or for javascript:

```
function validate(emailString) {
    return /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(emailString)
}
```

This will return true if the value for the emailString parameter is a valid email.

Comment: @Jim Elrod: may i know, where i can add in my script?  i need to show red color border, if any input field is blank or invalid.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have an input field in your HTML as such -

```
<form name="emailForm">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
</form>
```

In your javascript you can then add an event handler whenever a user activates 
the text field and then clicks elsewhere (or uses tab to navigate to the next field)

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
    // Instead of .blur() you can also just have the 
    // form submit event use the checkEmail() function.
    checkEmail();
});


function checkEmail(){
    var email = document.forms["emailForm"]["email"].value;
    var atnum = email.replace(/[^@]/g, '').length
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || email.length <= dotpos + 2   || atnum > 1) {
        // E-mail was not valid
        $('#email').css({border: '1px solid #e74c3c'});
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('#email').css({border: '1px solid #555'});        
        }, 800);
    } else {
        // E-mail was OK
        alert("You're good to go!");
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soxnm72d/%20fiddle)

Comment: it is not a problem create with html,, , i need to achieve with my code.. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not quite understand the problem. What do you mean by "need to achieve with my code"? You have a validate function in the comment of your question. You can swap that out with my checkEmail function.

Comment: i raised one more question here, if you know, please answer, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554798/javascript-email-validation-for-multiple-text-boxes/29554972?noredirect=1#comment47261703_29554972

Comment: Is it not the same question? If my answer fit your question and it works, why not accept it?

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without understanding your real need. You titled the problem as "email validation" in javascript, so that's what I gave you..